# Maple scalar triple product

Tags: multiplication, maple, scalar

Currently working on a math problem that requires maple to be solved.

The math problem is

The volume V pf the paralellpiped is given by the following scalar triple product.

```
V = |(P5->P8 X P5->P6) * P5->P1|
P1 = ( [-17/12] , [11/36], [-65/36])
P5 = ([-11/12], [-7/36], [-47/36])
P6 = ([-2/3],[-1/9],[-8/9])
P8 = ([-5/4],[-1/12],[-17/12])`
```

answer should be 4 cubic units.

Several times  trying it several different ways gives errors or nothing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you're getting errors, please post those in the body of your question, to allow others to know exactly what's going wrong. This can help you get answers quicker, and find the correct solution. Good luck!

Comment: Well I am following guides on the internet from googling Not a single one is working https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra%2FMultiply

this just gives Error, unknown operator etc.

Comment: It would still be beneficial to your question, if you put those errors in the question itself as it can help others better understand how to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with(Student:-MultivariateCalculus):
P1 := <-17/12, 11/36, -65/36>:
P5 := <-11/12, -7/36, -47/36>:
P6 := <-2/3, -1/9, -8/9>:
P8 := <-5/4, -1/12, -17/12>:
abs(TripleScalarProduct(P1-P5, P8-P5, P6-P5));


#1/18

#Executed in Maple 2018
```